# CLMath instead of Boost with PyOpenCL

Tags: boost, opencl, blas, pyopencl, boost-ublas

When I run configure.py during PyOpenCL setup, the only libs to direct to are boost and OpenCL.  Is it possible to Install CLMath (from AMD) and use that instead of uBLAS/BOOST?

I realize that BOOST is no longer required since V0.92, yet the config paths are only labelled for BOOST.